# Restrict product page using user Email Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to restrict product pages to certain users. So only certain users can see and pay for the product.

I want to be able to do this with their email they have signed up with. Once they sign up, i can show them a product specifically for them using their email addresses or user accounts.

I can get this working in Shopify of all things, but i cannot get this to work easily in Woocommerce.

So the steps.

All cart and shop redirects to login when logged out. 
User signs in and see's the cart/user accounts/shop. 
User see's only the products their allowed to. 
User cannot see other peoples products. 
User logs out and can now only see the login page and home page.

I have looked at a few plugins but they're really for doing subscriptions. I just want to simply select a user and block them from seeing anything other than the product or pages they're meant to see.

I can see how to redirect people when logged out. But when they're logged in i want to be VERY SPECIFIC about them only ever seeing one or more products that they're tagged to only.

I also want to hide the product or page so they can never see it without being given access to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this free plugin that handles this case.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/prices-by-user-role